# Filter for NAs only if group has more than 1 observation in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to be able to keep NAs for only groups that have more than two entries and just want to leave alone any groups that have 1 entry (regardless if they have NAs or not). That is, if the group has two elements, keep only the NA. If it has one then just take whatever is there. Here is a reprex of the type of data I have:

```r
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, NA_real_, 3, NA_real_),
  y = c("grp1", "grp2", "grp2", "grp3")
)
data
#>    x    y
#> 1  1 grp1
#> 2 NA grp2
#> 3  3 grp2
#> 4 NA grp3
```

Then here is the fairly ugly way I have achieved what I want:

```r
raw <- data %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(n = n())

results <- bind_rows(
  raw %>%
    filter(n == 2) %>%
    filter(is.na(x)),
  raw %>%
    filter(n == 1)
) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-n)

results
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>       x y    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1    NA grp2 
#> 2     1 grp1 
#> 3    NA grp3
```

Comment: Can you please share expected output? As per your problem, there must be one observation for group 2 having value 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach that works

```
data %>% 
  group_by(y) %>%  
  filter(!(!is.na(x) & n() > 1))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
# Groups:   y [3]
      x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 grp1 
2    NA grp2 
3    NA grp3
```

Comment: I think it is not really a big issue. We can interchange ` filter(!(!is.na(x) & n() > 1))` by ` filter(!( is.na(x) & n() > 1))` to get both solutions. It is all about the `!`.

Comment: True, I was just following OPs expected result, rather than his words. Lucky they get the answer to both!

Answer (score 4):

Update after clarification: We have only to add `!`  and change `==` to `>`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  filter(!(!is.na(x) & n() > 1))

      x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 grp1 
2    NA grp2 
3    NA grp3
```

We could define `filter` with the `max(row_number()`:
update: instead of `max(row_number()` we could use `n()` (many thanks to @Juan C)

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
   filter(!(is.na(x) & n() == 1))
 # filter(!(is.na(x) & max(row_number()) == 1))
```

```
     x y    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 grp1 
2    NA grp2 
3     3 grp2
```

Comment: You could simplify  `max(row_number()) == 1)` with `n() == 1`, right?

Comment: :-) Thank you very much I always forget this n().

Comment: Isn't the output here different to that expected in the Q? `result` from the OP kept x = NA for grp3?

Comment: I am confused. But I have understood " keep NAs for only groups that have more than two entries" sounds like the OP wanted to remove only the NA's where only one entry is in the group?! OP should clarify. Anyway the answer is different to one `!`

Comment: I've tried to clarify the question. But as @JoshWhite points out this is a different answer to the expected one.

Answer (score 1):

You specifically asked to do using `dplyr`, however, you can do this using `data.table`. It is more intuitive to follow:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data <- data[, N := .N, by = y][N <= 1 | !is.na(x)][, N := NULL]
data
```

Output:

```
   x    y
1:  1 grp1
2:  3 grp2
3: NA grp3
```

If the objective is to retain NAs cases if group has more than one observations, then follow:

```
data <- data[, N := .N, by = y][N <= 1 | is.na(x)][, N := NULL]
data
```

Output:

```
    x    y
1:  1 grp1
2: NA grp2
3: NA grp3
```

Comment: Same here - Isn't the output here different to that expected in the Q? `result` from the OP kept x = NA for grp3?

Comment: It read, filter NA if group has more than one observations. I thought, it means removing case of NA if group has more than one NAs.

Comment: "keep NA". Sorry for any confusion